# How to gain access to an element on the same level in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<div id="dad">
     <img id="mum">
     <input>
</div>
```

With jQuery, how could i get access to the input element, get is value or set it for example? I can't work out how to access something on the same level.. and i dont want to be using ID's, just parent/child nodes so i can use the code for loads of **dad** div's

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myEl = $("#dad").children(":input");
```

Comment: Thanks!
Although i modified to this........$(this).parent("div").children("input").val();

......THANKS!

Answer (score 6):

an addition to Zed,

```
$(this).parent().children('input');
```

if you give a name to your input field then you can easily select throughout the others,

```
$(this).parent().children('input[name=my_input]');
```

then you can give any value as:

```
$(this).parent().children('input[name=my_input]').val('any value');
```

Sinan.

Comment: Thanks :) got there before you commented :(

Answer (score 1):

$(this).parent().children() ?

Comment: when i upvoted you it was parent().children() siblings won't give the same output :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to find the first child input element:

```
jQuery("div").find("input:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand question, you would like achieve `input` from `mum` leve? 
So try `$("#mum ~ input")...`

BTW, great site to search jquery function by category http://visualjquery.com/ +nice example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to find siblings (node with same depth and same parent and in DOM tree)

`$(el).next()` - next element (sibling) for all elements in the set
`$(el).nextAll` - all following siblings 
`$(el).nextUntil` - all following siblings, stop on some condition (not including first "bad match").
Besides, you have next adjacent selector (+) and next sibling selector.

The same about prev, prevAll and prevUntil.
And you even have a siblings method.
Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=sibling) out.